# Group by time and aggregate in PromQL/MetricsQL

Tags: prometheus, promql, victoriametrics, metricsql

I have a metric say x, of type gauge, And the values are reported every 5m.

Now I want to make a query such that, I get sum of values in each hour in a day.

Exmaple: from 3PM to 5PM, the gauge values are 1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2 reported every 5 minutes - total 60 values

The result of my query should be 3PM-4PM -> 45 and 4PM-5PM -> 45 (sum of all values in the hour)

TIA

Answer (score 2):

See [Prometheus count query for a particular period](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64333156/prometheus-count-query-for-a-particular-period/64342278#64342278)

Just use `sum_over_time(x[1h])` instead and 3600 as resolution/step.