# Prometheus count query for a particular period

Tags: prometheus, promql

How can I get the Prometheus metrics count for a particular day ? For eg: I would need it for 24 hours, for the day 13-10-2020.

All I see is a way to get the count for the last 24 hours:

```
sum(increase(created_total[24h]))
```

How could I get the same count over 24 hours, but for a different day ? I spent quite some time trying to figure out a way but with no luck. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Start with Prometheus Graph Console and punch in `2020-10-13 23:59:59` into the `Moment`field:

[Moment field of Prometheus Graph Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaQTP.png)

There's a similar way with Graph. There's range (=number of days for which you want daily stats), end timestamp (`2020-10-13 23:59:59` in your case) and resolution (`86400` in your case, for 24h in seconds).